# Custom Keycloak Event Listener

Tags: spring-boot, events, keycloak, keycloak-services

Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2024-03-12 09:39:04,854 WARN  [io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ClassTransformingBuildStep] (build-18) Cannot transform com.expleo.msauth.entity.User_expleo as its containing application archive could not be found.
2024-03-12 09:39:11,757 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 16764ms
ERROR: Unexpected error when starting the server in (development) mode
ERROR: Failed to start quarkus
ERROR: Unable to load class [com.expleo.msauth.entity.User_expleo]
ERROR: com.expleo.msauth.entity.User_expleo
For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.

i have :

```
package com.expleo.msauth.event;

import org.keycloak.events.Event;
import org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProvider;
import org.keycloak.events.EventType;
import org.keycloak.events.admin.AdminEvent;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.RealmProvider;

public class CustomEventListener implements EventListenerProvider {
    private KeycloakSession session;

    public CustomEventListener(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("Hi this event listner when user had registration + "+event.getType().name());

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(AdminEvent adminEvent, boolean b) {
        System.out.println("Hi this event listner for admin when user had registration + "+adminEvent.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

and :

```
package com.expleo.msauth.event;

import org.keycloak.Config;
import org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProvider;
import org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProviderFactory;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class CustomEventListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        return new CustomEventListener(keycloakSession);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "CustomEventListener";
    }
}
```

i don't know why this error:
2024-03-12 10:22:49,376 WARN  [io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ClassTransformingBuildStep] (build-54) Cannot transform com.expleo.msauth.entity.User_expleo as its containing application archive could not be found.

I am using Keycloak Version 23.0.7 and jdk17 and I have configured Custom Event Listener in my spring boot project, I have done the mvn clean install and have copy pasted the jar file in the providers folder but when i start keycloak it gives me this error because user_expleo is simple class :

```
package com.expleo.msauth.entity;

import com.expleo.msauth.enums.Status;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data @Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User_expleo {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'OFFLINE'")
    private Status status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include the libraries in the jar file. And then use the -jar-with-dependencies.jar fiele from the target directory.
I use the following in my jar file

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>

                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```